# How to enable Jack Compiler support?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I have been troubling with Jack compiler. I use Intellij IDEA for Androidd app development.

I have read theese documentations:

[documentation for jack compiler](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html)

[how to use java 8 features](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Here is my build.gradle config:

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    ...
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile ('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.1') {
    // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
}
```

but still I get this error:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Gradle Build Error:

```
Error:(12, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'jackOptions()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'App' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Don't know how to figure this out.

Comment: You probably have a lib imported that is incompatible with jack, like android-apt

Comment: Added my dependencies.

Comment: Check if they're compatible..

Comment: The problem is that gradle can't find the jackOptions method

Comment: What versions of Gradle and Gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: Gradle version: 2.10 - Gradle plugin version: 2.0.0

Answer (score 1):

```
    defaultConfig {

         ...

       jackOptions {
           enabled true
       }

       // inside defaultConfig
       compileOptions { 
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
    }
```